# Backbone.js fetch method is not working

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I am fairly new to Backbone.js and I am trying to understand how it works to get data and post data to a REST api.
In the code below in Codeigniter I am trying to to fetch data from my REST api that is returning a json object.
Using an input field and a submit button, I am trying to pass the value to the controller function that should return the json data if the data is found in the database model.
From what I have understood, when calling fetch() the URL should change, but nothing happens when I press the button submit. Although if I manually enter a url in this format: *http://localhost/Codeigniter/index.php/testcontroller/getdatabasedata?searchvalue=Rome* I do get back the jason data.
What I need to do to submit the value from the input field to the controller function and display the results?

Thank you

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script language="Javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function () {
          var urlstr = "../../index.php/testcontroller/getdatabasedata?searchvalue="+this.get("name");
          return urlstr;
        },
        defaults: {
          name: null,

        }
      });

      var todoitem = new TodoItem();
      var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend(
      {
        el: '#container', 
        model: todoitem,

        initialize: function(){
          this.listenTo(this.model,"sync change", this.gotdata);
        },
        events: {
            "click #submitbtn" : "getdata",

          },
          getdata: function (event) {
            var celebname = $('#celebname').val();

            this.model.set({name:celebname});
            this.model.fetch();
          },
          gotdata: function () {
            var age = this.model.get("age");
            $('#age').html(age);
          },
      });
      var todoView = new TodoView();
});
</script>
```

Comment: The main problem is that you define `TodoItem` as `Collection`, but, in fact, use it as `model` in `TodoView`

Comment: @hindmost Initially it was Backbone.Model.extend, which still didn't worked, then I tried as a Collection.

Comment: `Model != Collection`. You cannot use Collection as Model. Start from reading [the manual](http://backbonejs.org/)

Comment: @hindmost Yes I am aware of that. But I can't understand why the URL is not changing when calling fetch()

Comment: Your `.fetch` call actually do nothing just because your model is malformed. So the URL doesn't matter since it never used.

Answer (score 0):

did the events  answer you, when you click  '#submitbtn', you can and a console.log in the function getdata()

Comment: smith I have added it, but nothing seems to happen in he console. This means that the event of clicking the button is not registering.

Comment: I have read that the button must be located in the container div. In my case it is, and should cause no problem.

Comment: are you sure, i run you code ,it run into  the function  getdata, just check if you have the '#submitbtn'

Comment: `
    getdata: function (event) {
                        var celebname = $('#celebname').val();

                        this.model.set({name:celebname});
                        this.model.fetch();
                        console.log('just try tu get request')
                    },
`

and the output is :
just try tu get request
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:63342/index.php/testcontroller/getdatabasedata?searchvalue=undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Do you have any idea why the function call is not working

Comment: Still nothing in the Chrome console. Here is my input: <input type=submit value="Get City" id="submitbtn">

Comment: <pre>
<div id="container">
    container
    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" name="submit">
</div>
</pre>

Comment: i do not think your code have wrong , it replace your input with my, i still can work, i am really no idea ...

Comment: ok, just be happy to help you ,recently i am learn backbone olse.

Comment: I know what it is: my contrainer was class="container" Should have been id="container"

Comment: So the function is working on submit button. Any ideea why why fetch() is not changing the URL so ti can call the REST api?

Comment: i think you should try to move the function generate url out of the model, for you can not  get value by :  this.get('name'), or this.name ,can you understand me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98979/discussion-between-otonel-and-john-simth).